# Перенести в функцию указатели на массивы и вывести их

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Помогите с лабораторной : Ввести не более 5 массивов целых чисел. Количество чисел в массиве задается во время
выполнение программы, это число записать первым элементом массива. Массивы разместить в
динамической памяти. Создать массив указателей на данные массивы. В функцию с переменным
числом параметров передать количество массивов и указатели на массивы. В функции вывести на
экран все элементы каждого массива.
Создал массив и выделил память

```
cout << "Введите количество элементов  : " << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int* A = new int[a];
    A[0] = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        A[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
//таким образом создал 5 массивов, далее массив указателей с выводом
    int*S[5]{ A,B,C,D,E };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << S[i] << "\t";
    }
```

Можно ли передать в функцию массив с указателем на массивы и уже с помощью него сделать вывод элементов? Моё решение этой задачи растянулось на 130 строчек кода , помогите пожалуйста решить

Comment: Читайте [variable argument lists](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) (кстати, там есть пример). А требуемая вам функция должна начинаться так -- `void print_n_arrays (int n_arrays, ...) { va_list ap; va_start(ap, n_arrays); for (int i = 0; i < n_arrays; i++) { int *a = va_arg(ap, int *); int n = a[0]; // ну, далее печать элементов очередного массива, с печатью заголовка и т.п. }}`

Comment: Ну как правильно написал avp в `c` существует механизм передачи переменного числа параметров в функции через макросы. Вот ссылочки  https://metanit.com/cpp/c/5.13.php https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments  
Второй подход - упаковать аргументы в контейнер из стандартной библиотеки, например `vector<>` или `list<>` и передавать в функцию уже контейнер. Правда у вас по заданию нужно первый вариант использовать.